# Python regex, propably easy

Tags: python, regex

I need some help

I have to split this string (code below) . I need to get values, for example "-125" "66" "-7" etc.

```
    self.current_position = "X-125.00 Y66.00 Z34.00 A-4.00 B-7.00 C-46.00"
    value = re.split('(-*\d\.*\d*)', self.current_position)
    print(value[0])
```

insteade I get "-7.00", see image below

"-125", "66" works fine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QmiE.png)

Can I get some hint what I am doing wrong, I spend like 3Hrs and can't handle this myself

Comment: Maybe `list(map(int,re.findall(r'(-?\d+)(?:\.\d+)?', current_position)))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Watch out for the int part! Coordinates could be non-integer, so float would be a better choice. But I like that you used the map function.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use a dict instead, because your coordinates could be in different order. Like this:

```
import re
def analyze_gcode(s):
    return {m[0]: float(m[1]) for m in re.findall('([A-Z])([0-9.-]+)', s)}
current_position = "X-125.00 Y66.00 Z34.00 A-4.00 B-7.00 C-46.00"
print(analyze_gcode(current_position))
```

outputs:
{'X': -125.0, 'Y': 66.0, 'Z': 34.0, 'A': -4.0, 'B': -7.0, 'C': -46.0}